# nodejs worker thread has it's timeout?

Tags: javascript, node.js, worker-thread

I use node worker thread to run a setTimeout loop in it,but i find it is not run as my expect.

Code in worker thread only run about 13 times and it stop without error.

```
// code in nodejs worker thread
const record = (taskName, count) => {
    console.log(`testrecord:${taskName}:${count}`);
    count++;
    clearTimeout(runningId);
    if (count < 10000) {
        runningId = setTimeout(() => {
            record(taskName, count);
        }, 1000);
    }
}

parentPort.on('message', async function (event) {
    const { taskName} = event;
    record(taskName, 0);
  }
```

```
// The console log result:

...
[ 'testrecord:threadtest_22:8' ]
[ 'testrecord:threadtest_22:9' ]
[ 'testrecord:threadtest_22:10' ]
[ 'testrecord:threadtest_22:11' ]
[ 'testrecord:threadtest_22:12' ]
[ 'testrecord:threadtest_22:13' ]
```

worker thread only run the code in setTimeout 13 times. not 10000 times. why?

Comment: Is `count` variable used somewhere else in the code?

Comment: Can you show us the code that creates the worker thread, to make a [mcve]?

Comment: count not used in other place

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to how many threads you have on the machine that is running the code. Each worker gets assigned to a thread when created.

It seems you have 14 threads hence it stopped at 13.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).